# link extracting script is casing issue in PHP

Tags: php, fopen

I have created a loop to extract specific links from google. but at the end when i am running this script it is creating empty file without any links.

```
for ($n=0;$n<500;$n+=10) 
{
$country = $_GET['country']; 
    // Country Changing array to scan through different countries.
        $google = array (
            "default" => array("google.com" , "countryUS"),
            "NZ" => array("google.co.nz" , "countryNZ"),
            "UK" => array("google.co.uk" , "countryUK|countryGB"),
            "AU" => array("google.com.au" , "countryAU")        
        );
// Variables for fopen
    $URL = 'www.'.$google[$country][0];
    $PORT = "80";
    $TIMEOUT = 30;
    $Q = $_GET['query'];


// Google String
$GET = '/search?q='.urlencode($Q).'&hl=en&cr='.$google[$country][1].'&tbs=ctr:'.$google[$country][1].'&start='.$n.'&sa=N';
    $fp = fsockopen($URL, $PORT, $errno, $errstr, $TIMEOUT);
    if (!$fp) 
    {
        echo "Error connecting to {$URL}<br>\n";
    } else 
    {
        $out = "GET $GET HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $URL\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        $buffer = '';
        while (!feof($fp)) 
        {
            $buffer .= fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        write($SITEs, filter($buffer));

    }
}
```

please tell me if i am doing anything wrong.

Note: **fopen is ON in my PHP.**

Adding:

```
    function write($A, $B) {
        @touch($A);
        $C = fopen($A, 'a');
        fwrite($C, $B);
        fclose($C);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot crawl Google like this. Try fetching the data and echoing it.

Comment: Get ready to face your IP block by Google for scrapping like this.

Comment: @anubhava ip get blocked with you try more than 900 links .. but i set a loop for 500  links .. so there is no issue

Comment: @Bibhas what do you mean by fetching and echoing ...?

Comment: `ip get blocked with you try more than 900 links` - source of this information?

Comment: @MuzammilHussain: Assuming your 900 information is correct and even if you have set a loop of 500, it will still not help since you'll be running your code multiple times to debug and test.

Comment: @anubhava mate its not the issue .. because when 1 start loop for 1 string.. it matter how many results i extract. means i want to extract links which are concerned with **photoshop**. so i simply use **photoshop** as a keywork and if i cross the limit of 900 link then my ip will be blocked by google. but if i change the keyword before 900 links then they won't block my IP. i hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened your file you're going to write in!

Also, there's no PHP function `write()`

Comment: well write function is in the scrtipt

Comment: i also add the funtion of `write()`